# Should you put quotes around type annotations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, static-typing

What's the difference between these two functions? I've seen people put quotes around type annotations and other times leave them out but I couldn't find why people choose to use one or the other.

```
def do_something(entity: Entity):
    pass
def do_something(entity: 'Entity'):
    pass
```

Are there advantages or disadvantages to any of these?

Comment: I think there was some chatter on a Python mailing list about making the resolution of type annotations lazy so you could define things later (in your example, define `Entity` below all the code).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Putting quotes around type hints is something that makes sense when making a [Forward Reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) according to PEP 484. In this case putting quotes around a name is used to subdue a NameError that would occur.

In other cases, don't use quotes, it doesn't result in the hint you want:

```
>>> def bad_foo(a: 'int'):
...     pass
>>> def good_foo(a: int):
...     pass
>>> bad_foo.__annotations__['a'] == good_foo.__annotations__['a']
False
```

though for now type checkers (mypy, atleast) don't seem to treat these differently, I wouldn't be sure if that would be the case in the future. Best to be clear and not use quotes when you actually don't need them.

Comment: [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) is the way to resolve type hints with forward references, if you need to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it can also cause runtime exceptions if you don't quote them in some situations. See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1145#issuecomment-817070510). I have no idea why, but it definitely does:

```
 ~ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 26 2021, 23:27:12)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def main() -> OrderedDict[str, str]:
...     x: OrderedDict[str, str] = OrderedDict()
...     print(x)
...     return x
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined
>>> def main() -> 'OrderedDict[str, str]':
...     x: OrderedDict[str, str] = OrderedDict()
...     print(x)
...     return x
...
>>>
```

However you can avoid it by using `from __future__ import annotations`.

Comment: The error message in your code is easily fixed: `from collections import OrderedDict`