# Understanding Python type annotation after indexing

Tags: python, syntax, type-hinting

I made a typo in my code and replaced an `=` with a `:`, which resulted in a line of code that looked like:

```py
data = {}
data["teapot"]: "turtle"
```

To my surprise, this did not produce a syntax error, but I don't understand what it's doing.

I then dumped the abstract syntax tree and it appears that it is some sort of type hint, although not one I've been able to find an example of elsewhere:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("data['x']: 'turtle'"), indent=2))
Module(
  body=[
    AnnAssign(
      target=Subscript(
        value=Name(id='data', ctx=Load()),
        slice=Constant(value='x'),
        ctx=Store()),
      annotation=Constant(value='turtle'),
      simple=0)],
  type_ignores=[])
```

What does this code mean?  If it is, as I guess based on the AST, a type hint, does it have any practical use?

Comment: You're simply declaring that the value of `data["teapot"]` has the type `turtle`.

Comment: @Barmar that would match with what the AST shows.  Do you know of any practical uses for the syntax?  As noted below both mypy and pyright reject it.

Comment: No, it's just a corner case in the grammar.

Comment: I think that answers my question - if you'd like to put it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from a combination of two features of type annotation syntax.

First, you can put a type hint after any expression that could syntactically be the target of an assignment. This includes identifiers (e.g. `data`), indexed expressions (e.g. `data["teapot"]`), attributes (e.g. `data.teapot`). It doesn't have to be an actual assignment; it's common to put type hints for variables at the beginning of a function or class, and fill in the value later.

Second, the type name can be a string literal, because this is used for forward references to types that haven't yet been defined. Forward references are needed when you have circular or recursive chains of type hints, to solve the chicken-and-egg problem.

So your example fits this case

```
data["teapot"]: "turtle"
```

It simply declares that the eventual value of `data["teapot"]` will be of the type named `turtle`, which may not yet be defined.

Answer (score 0):

[Type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in python is a way to write python in a statically typed manner. It generally has little effect on the runtime (technically still used but rare). More often, you use it with a static type checker like mypy, pylint or PyCharm IDE.

Using quote is doing [forward declaration](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references). See also: [Should you put quotes around type annotations in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458470/should-you-put-quotes-around-type-annotations-in-python)

Your code snippet is similar to the one here: [Type hints without value assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74308012/type-hints-without-value-assignment-in-python). However, it does not seem to actually add any annotations:

```py
a: int = 1
b: float
c = {}
c['foo']: str

print(__annotations__)
# results in
# {'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'float'>}
```

As for practical use, Pylint throws an error when checking, so this is probably not a standard syntax. Interstingly, expressions like `1+2+3: int` or `f(x): float` results in `SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation` at runtime, but not in this case. I'm guessing it's possible for some static type checker to use this syntax to annotate individual elements in arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: To be clearer, I'm familiar with type hints in general, it's this specific example with an index onto the variable that makes no sense to me.

Comment: I see. Then this has no use in pyright, which is used in vscode python extension, since it is an error. Not sure about other type checkers. Do you use a type checker where this does not throw an error? I'm curious to know.

Comment: If you use python >=3.11 or enable the new annotation system (`from __future__ import annotations`), those results are now strings and their classes cannot longer be accessed `{'a': 'int', 'b': 'float'}` but you can skip the forward declaration as the class is not longer needed.

Comment: @EJam I've only been testing in the Python interpreter.  Out of curiosity I did check with mypy and pyright and neither accepted it, so it seems an odd thing to have in the syntax.